# field repository in Service required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa, crud

How can I solve this problem in my crud application?
This is my error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repository in com.howtodoinjava.demo.service.UtentiServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

These are my classes

RepoConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "modelEntityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
    basePackages = { "com.howtodoinjava.demo" }
)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class RepoConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "modelDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "modelEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder 
    builder, @Qualifier("modelDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
    return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages(UtentiEntity.class)
                .persistenceUnit("unipass")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "modelSessionFactory")
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(@Qualifier("modelDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder localSessionFactoryBuilder = new 
        LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
        return localSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    @Qualifier("modelEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

UtentiEntity.java

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(schema = "BASE", name = "TA11_UTENTI")
public class UtentiEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="cod_utente")
    private String codUtente;

    @Column(name="nome")
    private String nome;

    @Column(name="cognome")
    private String cognome;

    @Column(name="societa")
    private String societa;

    @Column(name="via")
    private String via;

    @Column(name="codice_postale")
    private String codicePostale;

    @Column(name="citta")
    private String citta;

    @Column(name="stato")
    private String stato;

    @Column(name="societa_tassa_id")
    private String societaTassaId;

    @Column(name="vat")
    private String vat;

}
```

UtentiEntityRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface UtentiEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<UtentiEntity, String> {

}
```

UtentiService.java

```
public interface UtentiService {
    public UtentiEntity getUtentiEntityById(String id) throws RecordNotFoundException;
}
```

UtentiServiceImpl.java

```
    @Service
public class UtentiServiceImpl implements UtentiService{
    @Autowired
    private UtentiEntityRepository repository;

    @Override
    public UtentiEntity getUtentiEntityById(String id) throws RecordNotFoundException
    {
        Optional<UtentiEntity> utentiEntity = repository.findById(id);

        if(utentiEntity.isPresent()) {
            return utentiEntity.get();
        } else {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException("No employee record exist for given id");
        }
    } 
}
```

UtentiEntityController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/utenti")
public class UtentiEntityController
{
    @Autowired
    UtentiServiceImpl service;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UtentiEntity> getUtentiEntityById(@PathVariable("id") String id)
                                                    throws RecordNotFoundException {
        UtentiEntity entity = service.getUtentiEntityById(id);

        return new ResponseEntity<UtentiEntity>(entity, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.howtodoinjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2/jcc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Just create this bean in any configuration file :-)

Comment: may be spring hibernate version compatibility...

Comment: Maria you have a bit messy configuration here, the easiest way will be to generate entire project here https://start.spring.io/